# NodeJS - Third party Api call from app.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, post, http-post

I need to call 3rd party api from backend in NodeJS and return the data to ajax call in frontend

Below is my code:

```
router.post('/get_data', function(request, response){
var city_name = request.body.city_name;
if(city_name in city_name_done){

}
else {
    city_name_done.push(city_name);
    console.log('city_name: ' + city_name);
    var options = {
        host : 'api.openweathermap.org',
        path : '/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=' + city_name + '&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=14&appid=75e843de569fb57a783c2e73fd9a7bb5',
        method : 'GET'
    }
    var maybe = '';
    console.log('till here')
    var req = http.request(options, function(res){
        var body = "";
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('data came');
            body += data;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log('ended too');
            maybe = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(maybe.city);
        });
    });
    console.log('here too man');
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
    response.send(maybe);
}
});
```

I am able to get the city_name parameter from ajax post request from frontend side however I get 500 internal server error everytime I execute the post request

PS: Pardon my English and even the level of the question as I am an absolute beginner in NodeJS

Comment: is a path /get_data defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning response from outside of function call that gets data from 3rd party api. You need to return response from `res.on('end'` section. It is because api call is asynchronous and we have to wait for response to come.

```
res.on('end', function() {
     console.log('ended too');
     maybe = JSON.parse(body);
     console.log(maybe.city);
     response.send(maybe);
});
```

Complete code is

```
    router.post('/get_data', function(request, response){
var city_name = request.body.city_name;
if(city_name in city_name_done){

}
else {
    city_name_done.push(city_name);
    console.log('city_name: ' + city_name);
    var options = {
        host : 'api.openweathermap.org',
        path : '/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=' + city_name + '&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=14&appid=75e843de569fb57a783c2e73fd9a7bb5',
        method : 'GET'
    }
    var maybe = '';
    console.log('till here')
    var req = http.request(options, function(res){
        var body = "";
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('data came');
            body += data;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log('ended too');
            maybe = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(maybe.city);
            response.send(maybe);
        });
    });
    console.log('here too man');
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
    res.end();
}
});
```

Comment: hello  @Zohaib Ijaz  can u give me the answer my question ...my questions is when i hit the third party api then its not send the response like err or data .
how can i handle this situations in my node js applications.

Answer (score 0):

Well doing a simple 'GET' with Postman to `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Miami&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=14&appid=75e843de569fb57a783c2e73fd9a7bb5` does return results.

So it seems like you may be missing something like `var http = require('http');` maybe :)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use the `request` module in `npm`, makes requests way easier to handle. See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Firstly: `maybe` is not necessary here. You get a `JSON` string from the API, then you parse it into an object, but when you send it, you need to stringify it, yet again. So just stick with the incoming data in the string form.

Secondly: `response.send` is called outside of the `end` event: so what is happening is that - JavaScript being asynchronous - it will call the API, but not wait for the response to come back, because you are yourself already sending a response to your client. You need to put that into the `end` callback, in order to actually wait for the API.

So this is what I'd do:

```
router.post('/get_data', function(request, response){
var city_name = request.body.city_name;
if(city_name in city_name_done){
    return;
}
else {
    city_name_done.push(city_name);
    console.log('city_name: ' + city_name);
    var options = {
        host : 'api.openweathermap.org',
        path : '/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=' + city_name + '&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=14&appid=75e843de569fb57a783c2e73fd9a7bb5',
        method : 'GET'
    }
    console.log('till here')
    var req = http.request(options, function(res){
        var body = "";
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('data came');
            body += data;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log('ended too');
            console.log(maybe.city);
            response.send(body);
        });
    });
    console.log('here too man');
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: why not use axios on server side?

Answer (score 0):

Step-1 : `npm i --save request request-promise`

Step-2 : create file `helpers/callApi.js`

```
var httprequest = require('request-promise');

var callApi = async function(METHOD,URL,BODY=null,HEADERS=null){
     let headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    };
    if(HEADERS && Object.keys(HEADERS).length>0){
        headers = {...headers,...HEADERS}
    }
    var options = {
        method: METHOD,
        uri: URL,
        headers:headers,
        json:true
    };
    if(BODY){
        options.body =BODY;
    }
    let response = await httprequest(options).then((result)=>{
        return result; 
    }).catch(function (err){
        console.log(`HELPER API: ${URL} ERROR =`,err.message);
        return err;
    });
    return response;
}
module.exports = callApi;
```

Step-3 : require `callApi.js`

```
var callApi = require('./helpers/callApi');    
router.post('/get_data', async function(request, response){
   var city_name = request.body.city_name;
   let result = await callApi('GET',`https://api.openweathermap.org//data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${city_name}&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=14&appid=75e843de569fb57a783c2e73fd9a7bb5`);
   response.json(result);
});
```