# How do I get data from currency exchange rates API and save into MSSql database with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, orm, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I want to fetch data from https://openexchangerates.org/ API once I get the data from API I want to save API data into MSSql database and want to schedule at 10am

Anyone can provide similar example I can go through? It will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to schedule at 10 AM ?
Fetch data from the API -> Receive data -> Save data to Database

If you want the entire three steps to schedule every day at 10 AM, and since you are in node.js, you can use "cron" npm module to schedule that.

Use "cron" to schedule the task . The task is use any "fetch" or any similar ("request" npm module for example) to call the API and get the data , and finally save it to DB (MSSQL server, in your case).

Check "cron" documentation to get examples on how to schedule. Check "fetch" in MDN documentation. It returns a promise , so use the .then method to save the data to DB once you receive the data. Check independent examples on fetch.

---

Some more Info Added about how to call 3rd party API from Nodejs server side

---

[NodeJS - Third party Api call from app.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033751/nodejs-third-party-api-call-from-app-js)  https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback

Check these two. Once you receive the data, save the data to BD. Use "cron" to automatically schedule at 10 am every day.

Comment: Thanks Rupjyoti much appreciated your answer is useful also I wanted to know can you provide any useful link or example regarding Fetch data from the API -> Receive data -> Save data to Database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033751/nodejs-third-party-api-call-from-app-js  https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback                           Check these two. Once you receive the data, save the data to BD. Use "cron" to automatically schedule at 10 am every day.